# Python and MySQL: passing a list / tuple

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am building a query in Python to pass to a pymysql query.

`condition=['m']`
`query = "select * from table where condition in {}'.format(tuple(condition))`

The part I am stuck on is that I want to set up the script to work both for situation where `condition` can be a single item, or have multiple items.

Seemed to me that getting a list converted into a tuple would work, but it does not, because:
`tuple(condition)`
returns: 
`('m',)`
, which fails to work on my mysql server.

What is the easiest way to set this up that I can sent either a single value, or multiple values to the `where` clause on my query build in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I went with a different route, since these suggestions were either too cumbersome, or did not work.

The solution that worked for me is this: 
`cond = ', '.join('"{0}"'.format(w) for w in condition)`

and then the query is: 
`select * from table where condition in ({})`.format(cond)`

This generates a string of comma separated values, each value surrounded by quotation marks. Example:

```py
condition = ['baseline', 'error']
cond = ', '.join('"{0}"'.format(w) for w in condition)   
#"baseline","error"  
query = select * from table where condition in ({})`.format(cond)   
# select * from table where condition in ("baseline","error")
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method to use multiple conditions would be to have a format string for a single 'where':

```
fmtstr = "select * from table where condition in {} "
```

And something to add on to it:

```
addstr = "or condition in {} "
```

And concatenate them as needed.

For your tuple, you can address the items inside like you can with a list:

```
x = (1, 'a')
x[0] == 1  #evaluates True
x[1] == 'a'  #same
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to pass it as a string and let your sql server do the rest.
Have you tried :

```
query = "select * from table where condition in {}'.format(str(tuple(condition)))`
```

Comment: Once `.format()` is applied, `query` will be a string. I don't think the conversion changes anything.

Answer (score 1):

Another hack I could think of is to replace the last part of the query.

The problem usually occurs if you have a single element, that is it puts an unnecessary comma at the end like this `('m',)`

Why not do this:

```
condition = ['m']
queryString = 'SELECT o_id FROM orders WHERE o_k_id IN ' + str(tuple(condition))
queryString = queryString.replace(',)', ')')
print(queryString)
```

So your query will look like:

```
select * from table where condition in ('m')
```

In case you have to pass multiple values to your where condition, this will still hold true:

```
condition = ['m', 'n']
queryString = 'select * from table where condition in ' + str(tuple(condition))
queryString = queryString.replace(',)', ')')
print(queryString)
```

Output:

```
select * from table where condition in ('m', 'n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should solve your issue:

```
condition=['m', 'n']

def quoteWrap(path):
    return '"' + path + '"'

query = "select * from table where condition in ({})".format(','.join([quoteWrap(c) for c in condition]))
query
#select * from table where condition in ("m","n")
```

I've also added `quoteWrap` function to, obviously, wrap your strings in quotes.

Comment: Hey this is close to what I ended up with -- did not write a function, but did it directly (see my answer). This is by far the best and most flexible solution.